# Rayleigh Scattering and Red Giants

Tags: visible-light, astrophysics, scattering, stars, exoplanets

Rayleigh scattering is responsible for the color of the sky. Consider a planet with an atmospheric composition similar to Earth's but orbiting a red giant. Suppose further that the planet is in the habitable zone of the red giant.

My questions are these. What color would the sky be during the day on such a planet? What color would it be at sunrise and sunset? Would there be any other interesting effects on sky color?

Answer (score 0):

The star would appear between yellow to ored colour part of the spectrum in the afternoon.The sky Would appear a light yellowish as compared to our sky as the light coming from the star has more intensity of yellow light
During sunrise and sunset it would appear of course red.the sky would be in a yellow hue of blue.